Bare Bones – a semi-DIY crossword
This is part 64 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This is a semi-DIY crossword. Shade some cells in the grid so that the grid has mirror symmetry both horizontally and vertically (you can ignore the white diagonal lines). Fill the resulting grid so that the answers, using normal crossword numbering, correspond to the clues below.
Today I have visited a protected tropical rainforest which hosts a very impressive diversity of plant and animal life. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. They study earthquakes
8. (see 19 across)
9. Wrongly take the throne
10. Lennon's partner
11. Diminish in size
15. Young swan
18. Complete (a form)
19/8. Two-word rhyming cocktail
20. What a drawbridge may cross
21. Flashing star
24. The P in UPS
29. Escape
30. Underdog victory
31. Container for cookies
32. Mental disorder associated with paranoid delusions
Down
1. What archaeologists and web designers work on
2. More freezing
3. Grieve
4. Noisy
5. Dated term for a Roma person
6. Cuddle in a nestled position
7. Yell
12. Japanese short poem
13. Mull and Skye, say
14. Pol Pot's tongue
15. Cricket sound
16. Xbox owner, possibly
17. Make delighted
21. Around these —
22. Meal which can be "three-Martini"
23. Busy, like a beehive
25. Following
26. Francophone Louisianan
27. Butterfly-to-be, perhaps
28. Promptly (abbr.)

Gladys will return in Motion in the Ocean.

Gladys is visiting:

 Sinharaja Forest Reserve

Completed grid:

 

Across:

 1. They study earthquakes - SEISMOLOGISTS
 8. (see 19 across) - (Mai) TAI
 9. Wrongly take the throne - USURP
 10. Lennon's partner - (Yoko) ONO
 11. Diminish in size - SHRINK
 15. Young swan - CYGNET
 18. Complete (a form) - FILL
 19/8. Two-word rhyming cocktail - MAI (Tai)
 20. What a drawbridge may cross - MOAT
 21. Flashing star - PULSAR
 24. The P in UPS - PARCEL
 29. Escape - RUN
 30. Underdog victory - UPSET
 31. Container for cookies - JAR
 32. Mental disorder associated with paranoid delusions - SCHIZOPHRENIA

Down

 1. What archaeologists and web designers work on - SITES
 2. More freezing - ICIER
 3. Grieve - MOURN
 4. Noisy - LOUD
 5. Dated term for a Roma person - GYPSY
 6. Cuddle in a nestled position - SPOON
 7. Yell - SHOUT
 12. Japanese short poem - HAIKU
 13. Mull and Skye, say - ISLES
 14. Pol Pot's tongue - KHMER
 15. Cricket sound - CHIRP
 16. Xbox owner, possibly - GAMER
 17. Make delighted - ELATE
 21. Around these — - PARTS
 22. Meal which can be "three-Martini" - LUNCH
 23. Busy, like a beehive - A-BUZZ
 25. Following - AFTER
 26. Francophone Louisianan - CAJUN
 27. Butterfly-to-be, perhaps - LARVA
 28. Promptly (abbr.) - ASAP

Filling the grid:

 With the long answer to 1 across, and several of the initial down answers that hang from it, a lot of the grid could be determined straight away.

 Then, the answer to 9 across had only one possible location in the top half of the grid that also placed 8 and 10 on the same row.

 And the mirror symmetry rules completed most of the grid except for a few black squares around the centre.

Finding the answer:

 Finally, reading down the main diagonal (hinted at by the white lines in the given black squares) gives us SINHARAJA


Beat me by three minutes...well done!

Beat me by 2 hours well done !! I have no idea how you solved this so fast!
